# WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync unknown protocol error (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, oauth, uwp, oauth-2.0

I'm getting "The specified protocol is unknown." while getting token from MS OAuth. I can provide the user name and password OK. Get "Unknown Protocol Error" error after "Let this app access your info?" screen.

I use the following code:

```
Uri StartUri = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(ClientID) + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(CallbackUrl) + "&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(ScopeUrl);

Uri EndUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri(); 

WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResultCode = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, StartUri, EndUri);
```

Tried also `WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle`, same problem.

Same code works for Google (with `WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle` and `EndUri` "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?")

I'm using Universal app project in VS 2015.

This older post resolved the issue by changing web authentication options, but it does not seem to work for me on Win 10: [Exception thrown when WebAuthenticationBroker receives an OAuth2 callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742974/exception-thrown-when-webauthenticationbroker-receives-an-oauth2-callback)

Any help appreciated, I'm out of ideas here...

Comment: My first tought is: maybe the `EndUri` and the `CallbackUrl` have to be the same. But it's just an idea.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't help. BTW google works with different values. Ended up switching to MSAL.